# Current from guiding center drift under gravity

Tags: electromagnetism, energy

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guiding_center):

> when there is a force on the particles perpendicular to the magnetic field, then they drift in a direction perpendicular to both the force and the field.

This is called "guiding center drift". That article then goes on to apply this to special cases, such as the force being gravity. It also explicitly connects the dots to this drift being an electrical current.

From that article I'm led to believe I can construct a linear generator with a simple thin rectangular permanent magnet. If the magnet is made of a conducting material and its field is perpendicular to the plane of the magnet, then I should be able to attach wire leads to two opposing edges and obtain a non-zero current when the device is accelerated in the direction between the other two edges.

For example, this is a permanent magnet (made of a conducting material) magnetized so that the field is coming out of the screen:

```
           +-----+
           |     |
(+) wire --+     +-- wire (-)
           |     |
           +-----+
```

If it is accelerated up or down the screen then I think the Lorentz force would generate a current through the wires (assuming the circuit is completed). The measured voltage and current would be very small, yet non-zero.

What would happen if I oriented this device so that the accelerating force is gravity? e.g. if I let it rest in the proper orientation on a table. Now I accept the conservation of energy as much as the next guy, so I know the current ought to be zero. But why? I think I must be missing something simple.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your set-up: if there is no relative motion between the magnet and the wire loop, there will be no change in magnetic flux through the loop and no EMF induced. Or are you suggesting that you drop either the loop or the magnet? If one of them is dropped then there will be relative motion and gravitational potential energy of the dropped object will be converted into EMF through the wire loop and into kinetic energy of the dropped object. The reduction of the conversion between GPE and KE is sometimes striking, e.g. dropping a strong magnet through a copper tube.

Comment: @Diffycue from my reading of [homopolar generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homopolar_generator) I learned this interesting fact: the rotational energy of a homopolar generator is converted to electrical energy by the Lorentz force _even when the magnet is rotating with the disc_. From that I infer that the disc can simply be the magnet (not two separate parts). I'm assuming the same would hold true in my linear/rectangular case?

Comment: @Diffycue cont'd Meaning that normally for a linear generator you would move a conductor perpendicular to a magnet producing the magnetic field and a current would be generated perpendicular to both, but I'm assuming the magnet could move with the conductor, or better yet they could be a single thing.

Comment: The Faraday law applies to thin wires; in the case of the homopolar generator you have a finite conducting material. I believe this is the distinction that needs to be made between the two cases.